# Разделить строку не через char, а через string

Tags: c#, строки

Имеется строка

```
string str = "123|&|321|&|323|&|121";
```

Нужно разделить данную строку посимвольно и записать в массив.

Я понимаю что можно создать функцию и т.д. Но можно как то перегрузить `String.Split()`
Конечный результат должен быть таким

```
{ 123, 321, 323, 121 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.Split(new string[] { "|&|" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

[Доки по string array overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx), [руссиш версион](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)